# Get github repository using Azure devops REST API

Tags: azure, rest, github, azure-devops, postman

I am using postman and Azure Devops REST API to create some repositories ([https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0))
After that I need to transfer or clone a repo from another projet to the new one but it is not possible with the API. The only way is to get an .git file so I put the repo in a private github but I don't know how to pass the credentials into PostMan. I tried with a public one, it worked.

Comment: How to clone repo code to local using API? which API we can use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using Rest API to import Private Repo to new repo:

You need to create an "other git" service connection first, then you could use the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/import%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#gitimportrequestparameters) to import the Github Private Repo to New Repo.

Please refer to the following steps:

Step1: Create an **Other Git** Service connection.

You could use [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to create it.

For example:

```
Post https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=6.0-preview.4
```

Request Body sample:

```
{
    "authorization":{"scheme":"UsernamePassword","parameters":{"username":"{User name}","password":"{Password}"}},
    "data":{"accessExternalGitServer":"true"},
    "name":"{name}",
    "serviceEndpointProjectReferences":[{"description":"","name":"{Service connection name}","projectReference":{"id":"{Project Id}","name":"{Project Name}"}}],
    "type":"git",
    "url":"{Target Git URL}",
    "isShared":false,
    "owner":"library"
}
```

Or you could create it in **Project Settings -> Service Conntions -> New Service Connection -> Other Git**

Then you could get the **ServiceEndPointId**, and you could use it in the Import Repo Rest API.

For example:

URL

```
Post https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/{Project Name}/_apis/git/repositories/{Repo Name}/importRequests?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Request Body:

```
{
  "parameters": {
    "gitSource": {
      "url": "Git URL"
    },
    "serviceEndpointId": "{Service EndPoint Id}",
    "deleteServiceEndpointAfterImportIsDone": true
    
  }
}
```

Comment: How to clone repo code to local using API? which API we can use ?