# I have a code in Github repo and wants to clone/copy it to the Azure repository, Is there any way to do it via Rest

Tags: rest, curl, azure-devops, azure-repos

I have a code in Github repo and wants to clone/copy it to the Azure repository, Is there any way to do it via Curl

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Clone URL is incorrect' when importing from GitHub to Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60321498/clone-url-is-incorrect-when-importing-from-github-to-azure-devops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to do it via Curl

Yes. The method exists.

You need to use curl to run the following Rest API to create **Other Git** Service connection.

```
Post https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=6.0-preview.4
```

curl example:

```
curl -X  POST \
-u USERName:PAT  "https://dev.azure.com/org/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=6.0-preview.4" \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{ 
    "authorization":{"scheme":"UsernamePassword","parameters":{"username":"{User name}","password":"{Password}"}},
    "data":{"accessExternalGitServer":"true"},
    "name":"{name}",
    "serviceEndpointProjectReferences":[{"description":"","name":"{Service connection name}","projectReference":{"id":"{Project Id}","name":"{Project Name}"}}],
    "type":"git",
    "url":"{Target Git URL}",
    "isShared":false,
    "owner":"library"

}'
```

Then you could use the importRequests Rest API to import the Github Repo to Azure Repo.

```
Post https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/{Project Name}/_apis/git/repositories/{Repo Name}/importRequests?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

For more detailed info, you could refer to my another ticket: [Get github repository using Azure devops REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64320732/get-github-repository-using-azure-devops-rest-api)

This method is more complicated. I suggest that you could directly import the github repo with the **Import  repository** option in Azure Repo.

[image]

You could import the clone URL and auth info, then the repo will be directly cloned to Azure Repo.

Comment: Thanks a lot kevin, This answers my question. You were of great help.